# unexpected '$mm' (T_VARIABLE) in wp-includes/functions.php

Tags: 500-internal-error

I have a few Wordpress sites and all are down:

> An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was
>   attempting to fulfill the request. Error code: 500

When I look at the apache log, there are errors (for different sites):

```
[Mon Apr 15 04:00:28 2013] [error] [client ...] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$mm' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/SITEA/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 192, referer: http:...
[Mon Apr 15 04:00:55 2013] [error] [client ...] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$mm' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/SITEB/html/blog/wp-includes/functions.php on line 183
[Mon Apr 15 04:01:42 2013] [error] [client ...] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$mm' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/SITEC/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 203
```

How can I fix the error? Or is it related to [the recent wordpress attack](http://it.slashdot.org/story/13/04/12/1940248/wordpress-sites-under-wide-scale-brute-force-attack)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct line number for this variable in the most recent WordPress version are 207 and 209. So I guess something has mangled your files.

It is impossible to answer what exactly happened without seeing that code.

Look for new user accounts, and re-upload all WordPress files from [the source](http://wordpress.org/download/).